# Windows 7/8 can't connect to an N Router

Tags: windows, linux, mac, wireless-networking

I have a router running OpenWRT backfire, with N and A/B/G being broadcast. A linux laptop, and a Mac laptop can see the N network and connect to it (or at least they could last weekend). But there is now a Windows 7 Desktop with a B/G/N wireless card, and a Windows 8 Laptop with a B/G/N wireless card that can't see the N network only the B/G broadcast. The B/G and N have different SSID's and Encryption ( WEP and WPA2 PSK respectively ). The N SSID isn't even visible. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to troubleshoot further? Or what might be the cause?

**update wireless info**

Desktop

```
Dell Wireless 1502 802.11b/g/n
Atheros Communications Inc
9.2.0.412
```

Comment: Try playing with the channels...also what is the model and make of the wireless card?

Comment: What is the **exact** model of each of the wireless cards on the Windows desktop and laptops.  Without this information we cannot help.

Comment: I've added the desktop information, I'll have to get the laptops later, it's a lenovo though, so should be a different card/driver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible causes, on router config:

- "broadcast ssid" should be on, on both 5Ghz (a/n) an 2.4Ghz (b/g/n) Channel
- on 2.4Ghz do not use channel above 11 (do not use 12,13,14), as the notebooks firmwares' could only allow until 11, and filter or not even scan for channels 12,13 or 14.

Also, I will suggest on the router config to be sure about compatibility issues:

- put the 2.4Ghz band on mixed mode (b/g , n)
- put the 5.Ghz band on mixed mode (a , n)

The authentication mode (wep and wpa2)  should not be and issue with seeing the networks.

Even if you not seee the newtorks on the scan results (with an N card you should see both networks on 2.4 and 5 GHz), try to manually add the networks on the devices and see if you can connect to them.

*ps*: I cannot comment on your original question. I should answer, or PM -less usefull to the comunitty I think-, as my only means to communicate with you.

Comment: after reading this and thinking about it, I realize 2 problems 1, these new comps are b/g,n where I think the apple/linux are a/b/g/n, and the router was set to n for a/n only.